# How do I use colors in the MOTD?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, colors, motd

I edited [the default `/etc/update-motd.d/00-header`](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/e3e7d58d81328779f630), adding some color to make it easier to read:

```
printf "Welcome to \e[1;34m%s\e[0m \e[2m(%s %s %s)\e[0m\n" "$DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION" "$(uname -o)" "$(uname -r)" "$(uname -m)"
```

I can run that line of code just fine in a terminal, but when I edit `00-header` with this information, I get the escape codes printed out in plaintext:

```
Welcome to \e[1;36mUbuntu 13.10\e[0m \e[2m(GNU/Linux 3.11.0-23-generic i686)\e[0m
```

How can I add a splash of color to the message of the day?

Comment: How did you edit the file, especially the non-printable chars?

Comment: In `pico` I replaced the existing line of code with the first line o code that I included in my example. The problem is the MOTD parser then treated the `\e` and subsequent characters as plain-text instead of as special characters.

Comment: I see from the copyright headeer of the linked file you are on Ubuntu indeed, so I add the respective tag, as it's relevant for answering (regarding shell used, see my answer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are on Ubuntu - which uses dash to run system scripts:

That file, `/etc/update-motd.d/00-header`, is executed by **`/bin/dash`**, (not `/bin/bash`,) which is pretty minimalistic (and fast) -
it seems to not support the **"\e"** in this place - use **"\033"** instead.

It is different in when to expand escape codes.

Comment: Using hard-coded escape codes is not good practice. See other answers for how to use `tput`

Answer (score 10):

On Debian/Ubuntu the `motd` is configured in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

which means that upon successful login the system will run something like:

```
cat /run/motd.dynamic
if [[ -f /etc/motd ]]; then cat /etc/motd; fi
```

where `/etc/motd` is the static part (only printed, not sourced).

**Debian 9 / Ubuntu 16.04**:

For generating the dynamic part `run-parts` is used for `/etc/update-motd.d` directory:

```
/usr/bin/env -i PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d
```

For slightly more readable code you can use `tput setaf {color number}`. Note that to preserve colors we have to set `TERM` variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
export TERM=xterm-256color

read one five fifteen rest < /proc/loadavg
echo "$(tput setaf 2)
Kernel: `uname -v | awk -v OFS=' ' '{print $4, $5}'`
$(tput setaf 4)Load Averages......: ${one}, ${five}, ${fifteen} (1, 5, 15 min)
$(tput setaf 5)
 ______________
< Hello World! >
 --------------
        \\   ^__^
         \\  (oo)\\_______
            (__)\\       )\\\/\\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

$(tput sgr0)"
```

save the file as e.g. `/etc/update-motd.d/10-uname`

and make sure it's executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/update-motd.d/10-uname
```

Basic colors are numbered:

- 1 – Red
- 2 – Green
- 3 – Yellow
- 4 – Blue
- 5 – Magenta
- 6 – Cyan
- 7 – White

The code above generate:
[image: bash colored motd]

Depending on your taste you can produce more colorful output using `lolcat` or headings from `figlet`. Generated output uses standard bash syntax:

```
^[(B^[[m
^[[32m
Kernel: 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04)
^[[34mLoad Averages......: 0.04, 0.05, 0.05 (1, 5, 15 min)
^[[35m
 ______________
< Hello World! >
 --------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

^[(B^[[m
```

**Debian 8 / Ubuntu 14.04**

The dynamic part is updated using `/etc/init.d/motd start` that executes following:

```
uname -snrvm > /var/run/motd.dynamic
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert an ANSI `<ESC>` escape character before the color code. If you are using Vim, it would be pressing `Ctrl+K ESC` or `Ctrl+v+[` in edit mode.

```
^[
```

Then write the color code you want. For example, let it be red foreground `[31m`

```
^[[31mHello! Glad to see you again^[[0m
```

The starting `^[` should be an indicator that there is an escape character, and `[31m` the real characters typed by hand.